# auf etw hinweisen vs. auf etw verweisen

Tags: difference

Verweisen hat mehrere Bedeutungen (1. jdn des Landes / von der Schule verweisen 2. jdn an jdn verweisen). Aber wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen **auf etw hinweisen** und **auf etw verweisen**?

Ich weiß nur, dass *verweisen* ziemlich oft zusammen mit dem Wort - "*Link*" benutzt wird (z.B. Der Link verweist auf die Webseite des Ministeriums).

Beispiele (Duden):

- ein Hinweisschild verweist auf die Einfahrt (Kann man hier statt
  "verweisen" "hinweisen" verwenden?)
- jemanden auf die gesetzlichen Bestimmungen, auf die Vorschriften
  verweisen (= hinweisen?)

Andere Beispiele:

- Der Lehrer verweist auf ein medizinisches Buch (auf etw verweisen =
  empfehlen, vorschlagen oder erwähnen?)
- In dem Artikel, den ich gestern gelesen habe, wird auf einen
  interessanten Podcast zum Thema "Öko - Fashion" verwiesen (DW Deutsch
  lernen) (kurz erwähnt, berührt?)

Comment: Ein Verweis auf etwas ist ein Hinweis, an welcher Stelle Du mehr nachlesen kannst.

Comment: Ich frage mich, ob eine *Definition der Bedeutung* wirklich ist, was du brauchst. *Hinweisen* und *verweisen* haben stark überlappende Bedeutungen. Man kann versuchen, sie zu differenzieren, aber ich fürchte, man gerät da in ein Gestrüpp, da der Unterschied möglicherweise weniger in der Semantik zu suchen ist als in der Pragmatik: In welchen Fällen wird welches Wort benützt? Deine kleine Sammlung von Beispielsätzen geht ja schon in diese Richtung.

Answer (score 4):

Die Bedeutungen von hinweisen und verweisen überlappen stark, wie Christian Geiselmann in seinem Kommentar bereits klar gemacht hat.

Worin sie sich allerdings unterscheiden, ist die grundsätzliche Intention einer Aussage.

Hinweisen ist dabei weniger zwingend gemeint. Ich weise auf etwas hin, was der Empfänger des Hinweises beachten kann oder auch nicht.

Verweisen dahingegen ist restriktiver und enthält oft implizit die Information "hier geht es nicht weiter". Es kann als eine Art "Umleitung" verstanden werden.

Nehmen wir die Beispiele aus der Frage:

> Ein Hinweisschild verweist auf die Einfahrt

Diesen Satz würde ich erwarten im Kontext eins Schildes, das an einer Ausfahrt hängt: Es besagt "hier geht es nicht weiter" und zeigt auf die zu verwendende Einfahrt.

> Ein Hinweisschild weist auf die (andere) Einfahrt hin

Abgesehen vom stilistisch nicht schönen Deutsch (Wiederholung von Hinweis im selben Satz) würde man dieses Konstrukt an einem Schild an einer Einfahrt erwarten, das auf eine weitere Einfahrt hinweist, die man EBENFALLS benutzen kann.

Dasselbe funktioniert beim zweiten Beispielsatz:

> jemanden auf die gesetzlichen Bestimmungen, auf die Vorschriften verweisen

Bedeutet: Es ergibt keinen Sinn, hier weiter zu diskutieren, die gesetzlichen Bestimmungen sind die Ursache für *insert reason here*. Wenn man mehr erfahren möchte, muss man dort weiterlesen.

Im Gegensatz dazu:

> jemanden auf die gesetzlichen Bestimmungen, auf die Vorschriften hinweisen

Das würde man dann tun, wenn jemand etwas gegen diese Bestimmungen tut, und man auf die gesetzlichen Bestimmungen aufmerksam machen möchte, ohne zwingend daraus Konsequenzen zu ziehen.

Und als letztes Beispiel:

> Der Lehrer verweist auf ein medizinisches Buch

Kann interpretiert werden als: Wenn Ihr meine Aussage verifizieren / hinterfragen wollt, dann schaut in dieses Buch... Wird z.B. verwendet, um Diskussionen über den Wahrheitsgehalt einer Aussage des Lehrers zu unterbinden.

Auch hier wieder der Gegensatz:

> Der Lehrer weist auf ein medizinisches Buch hin

Das Buch dient der "weiteren Lektüre", hilft u.U. in der Vorbereitung z.B. auf die nächste Klausur, ist aber nicht zwingend notwendig.

Answer (score 3):

*Auf etwas hinweisen* bedeutet meist, dass man die Aufmerksamkeit auf etwas lenken möchte, was der andere übersehen oder (nach der eigenen Meinung) nicht hinreichend berücksichtigt hat.

*Auf etwas verweisen* hat in der Hauptbedeutung, dass man ein Thema gar nicht weiter vertiefen möchte, sondern eine Referenz angibt, in der (möglicherweise auch sehr umfangreiche) zusätzliche Informationen zu finden sind.